# Ошибка в Maven при работе с модулями в Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

При попытке собрать проект с помощью команд maven clean install, получается вот такая ошибка.

Мой `pom.xml`:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>OOP</groupId>
    <artifactId>Lab2</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <modules>
        <module>GraphicsEditor</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Launch</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

А также второго модуля 'pom.xml':

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>Lab2</artifactId>
        <groupId>OOP</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>GraphicsEditor</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Launch</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image: Структура проекта]
[image: Ошибка во время сбора второго модуля]

Comment: добавь полностью то, что ты написал в pom.xml

Comment: В ответы пишут ответы) ты можешь редактировать свой вопрос сколько угодно. Удали сам свой ответ, пока твой ответ другие не закрыли

Comment: Э-э-э, прошу прощения за тупейший вопрос: но как?

Comment: Все, ты убрал свой ответ)

Comment: Как я понял, ты хочешь сделать запускаемый jar-файл?)

Comment: У меня просто два модуля, нужен ли pom.xml второго модуля?

Comment: Да, и это тоже.

Comment: У тебя 2 pom'a?

Comment: Да, для каждого модуля соответственно

Comment: У тебя jdk 9? или какой версии?

Comment: Да, если быть точным 9.0.4.

Comment: Вдобавок у меня ещё и fxml не читается из папки resources... Эх...

Comment: Еще один момент, можешь скинуть скрин Project Structure (левую панель с папками и файлами). См пример тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984402/how-to-create-maven-multi-module-project-in-intellij

Comment: Да, конечно. Сейчас прикреплю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Версия Java: **9.0.4+**
>
> Версия Maven: **3.6.0**

То, что ты хочешь реализовать, называется [Maven Multi-Module](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module).
Полезная ссылка на stackoverflow - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once)

Чтобы избежать ошибок, сделаем все пошагово:

Как в итоге мы должны видеть наш проект:

```
.  
├── GraphicEditor  
│   └── src  
│       ├── main  
│       │   ├── java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           └── java
└── Processor
    └── src
        ├── main
        │   ├── java
        │   └── resources
        └── test
            └── java
```

1 - Создаем Maven-проект (с артефактом, допустим `core`). Удаляем папку `src`.
2 - Заходим в `File->Project Structure`. Выбираем в левой панеле `Modules`.
3 - Нажимаем `+ -> New Module -> Maven`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 - Дойдя до данного шага (см. картинку выше), нажимаем на `...` у `Add as module to` и выбираем наш родительский класс `core`. То же самое делаем при нажатии на `...` у `Parent`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

5 - Нам остается только придумать название модулю в `ArtefactId` (в твоем случае это `Graphic Editor`.

6 - Нас после нажатии кнопки `Finish` оставляет все еще в разделе `Module` и мы повторяем шаги 3-5 для модуля с именем `Processor`.

В итоге мы получаем вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, в те `pom.xml`, где у нас есть запускаемый класс, вставляем вот такую структуру. [Ссылка на оргинал](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven):

**Обрати внимание, что `<mainClass>` дожен быть заменен на маршрут к твоему запускаемому классу!**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    Hello2
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> Как выглядит `pom.xml` **Core**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <groupId>OOP</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>GraphicEditor</module>
        <module>Processor</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

> `pom.xml` **Graphic Editor/Processor**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <groupId>OOP</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>GraphicEditor</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        Hello1
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Как работать делать jar для каждого модуля теперь?
Вот так:

1 - в правой части экрана выбираем `Maven`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2 - Далее выбираем `core` и в нем просто нажимаем `install`.

После этого у тебя в каждом модуле появится папка `target`, в котором будет два файла:

- name.jar
- name-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Если у тебя нет `dependencies` - то оставляешь себе `name.jar`, если есть - `name-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Надеюсь, что я помог тебе

**UPDATE1:**
Как вызывать один модуль в другом - [ссылка](https://easyjava.ru/ecosystem/buildtools/maven/mnogomodulnye-proekty-maven/)

Comment: Теперь он ругается на 3.6.0

Comment: @ЖеняМарков сделай 2.6

Comment: Всё равно ...  'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project. @ line 13, column 21

Comment: @ЖеняМарков в parent измени `Lab2` на `Lab`

Comment: Тогда ошибка будет

Comment: @ЖеняМарков убери <parent> тогда вообще)

Comment: Та-а-ак, я убрал эту строчку с parent и у меня собрался модуль Lab2, но GraphicsEditor выдал ошибку

Comment: @ЖеняМарков ссори, что так долго, я с этим не работал, но мне интересно решить проблему. Давно хотел Multi-modules использовать)

Comment: @ЖеняМарков вот что я сейчас читаю https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once

Comment: да, я тоже хотел как-то структурировать проект, мне надо будет ещё модуль один добавить, но для начала вообще разобраться бы с зависимостями

Comment: @ЖеняМарков я кажется нашел ответ... Это как раз из той ссылки, что скинул. Сейчас обновлю свой ответ

Comment: @ЖеняМарков изменил ответ

Comment: @ЖеняМарков попытка №25)

Comment: Всё ещё та же ошибка...

Comment: @ЖеняМарков какая из?)

Comment: Которая на втором изображении.

Comment: @ЖеняМарков 3.6.0 на 2.6 изменил?

Comment: Да, именно. Однако он всё равно выделяется красным.

Comment: @ЖеняМарков между делом пока... может тебе обновить Maven? [Добавление новой версии Maven в IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/Flibberty-GEA/blog/wiki/03-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-Maven-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-IDE-%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-GitHub.)

Comment: Он у меня 3.6.0

Comment: @ЖеняМарков понял. тогда оставляем 3.6.0)

Comment: @ЖеняМарков попробуй 2 вещи: 1 - удалить <build> из второго pom.xml

Comment: 2 - вставить такой же <build> как и у родителя

Comment: само собой ) Может дело в зависимостях второго?

Comment: @ЖеняМарков читаешь мои мысли

Comment: Тем не менее, он всё равно ругается на 2.6

Comment: @ЖеняМарков сделай еще раз скрин ошибки, если не трудно... И (я просто кода не вижу) убедись, что везде стоит 3.6.0 вместо 2.6

Comment: Та-а-ак, новая информация сменил: на 3.6.0 и получил другую ошибку. Сейчас прикреплю скриншот.

Comment: @ЖеняМарков скрин в студию (с) Поле чудес для программистов

Comment: Так-с, прикрепил: последний самый

Comment: @ЖеняМарков уже лучше. Читаю сейчас это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525139/maven-build-compilation-error-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-plugins

Comment: @ЖеняМарков измени 9.0.4 везде на 9

Comment: Всё тоже самое...

Comment: @ЖеняМарков измени тогда на 1.8 (люблю риски)

Comment: Воу-воу, 1.8 :D Полегче

Comment: @ЖеняМарков А вдруг?)

Comment: Ну, нет. Это так не работает :D

Comment: @ЖеняМарков сделай 1.8

Comment: Так уже, и явно впустую.

Comment: @Mark194 блин... Я только что обновил свой JDK до 11 и такая же ошибка у меня, когда я ставлю `таргет` и `source` 10

Comment: <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>

Comment: Вообще мне вот интересно, зачем они в 11 убрали библиотеки с предыдущих...

Comment: @Mark194 хороший вопрос

Comment: Я же говорю: смена на 1.8 не меняет наличие ошибки

Comment: @Mark194 нашел новый вариант `build` - у меня он сработал

Comment: Так-так. Что же там такое?

Comment: @Mark194 1 - это "какая-то новая фича". 2 - мне кажется, что в <build> -> <mainClass> ты использовал название моего класса (мой косяк)

Comment: @Mark194 обновил ответ

Comment: @Mark194 только build копируй

Comment: встречал похожую конструкцию, но нет, не заработало

Comment: Та же ошибка? P.S. скинь те два pom'a в свой вопрос

Comment: Да, всё тоже самое. Добавил xml

Comment: Как я говорил ранее, ты забыл везде изменит на 9.0.4 и <mainClass> у тебя с именем `Launch`. `Launch` -  это main class одного из моих проектов

Comment: А во втором модуле вместо Launch мне что указывать?

Comment: @Mark194 я изменил код в ответе. тупо скопируй полностью второй пом - в пом `GraphicsEditor`, а первый пом - в пом `Lab2_OOP`

Comment: @Mark194 путь к Main в модуле `GraphicsEditor ` - form.Main

Comment: @Mark194 я опять накосячил... Для второго Pom - <mainClass>
                                        form.Main
                                    </mainClass>

Comment: вместо `sample.Main`

Comment: Я так и понял. Попробую, но всё-таки нам точно не нужно указывать зависимости?

Comment: Уф, ошибка всё та же...

Comment: @Mark194 да блин...

Comment: Да, и без зависимости у меня не запускается проект... хотя он при запуске кидает ошибку, ссылаясь на отсутствие fxml в папке ресурсов

Comment: Нету... Может, проект скинуть?

Comment: Отправил, залил в репу. Могу скачать дискорд, если это даст что-то

Comment: @Mark194 принял

Comment: А как тебя там найти?

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!! Всё заработало! У меня ещё дополнительная была проблема: забыл в глобальных переменных сменить jdk на 9 версию. В общем всё получилось, может, не стоило так подробно расписывать, но за полноту ответа отдельное спасибо.

Comment: @Antonio112009 а блок схемку для того, как проект в Intelij Idea должен выглядеть, ты сам прорисовывал или с помощью ресурса? Приятно смотрится.

Comment: @invzbl3 я буквально вчера о ней узнал. Говорят, в винде она предустановлена. назвается `tree`. Я устанавливал на мак с помощь Homebrew - `brew install tree`. На Ubuntu - `sudo apt-get install tree`

Comment: @invzbl3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518646/tree-view-of-a-directory-folder-in-windows

Comment: чтобы посмотреть только директории - `tree -d`

Comment: @invzbl3 идею с деревом я взял тут - [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034544/how-to-structure-a-multi-modules-maven-project-to-compile-it-at-once)